# Pattern matching on arguments of a cli tool

Tags: haskell, io, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a fairly simple tool in haskell to open up a file if you pass the -o argument and then the file, however I want it to have some functionality even if you only pass one argument, this has lead me to a wierd issue:
The program compiles just fine without warnings or errors but when i pass the -o argument with a file (that yes does exist) to the program nothing happens except an ambiguous error:
Non-exhaustive patterns in function parse

This is my code:

```
module Main where

import System.Environment
import System.Exit
import Data.List
import Data.Char

----------------
-- Main function
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    args <- getArgs
    fileName <- parse args
    let filePath = "$HOME/" ++ fileName
    fileContents <- readFile filePath

    putStrLn "This is the contents of your given file: "
    print fileContents

-----------------------
-- Parsing of arguments

parse []         = noArgs >> exitSuccess
parse ["-h"]     = usage  >> exitSuccess
parse ["-o"]     = noPage >> exitSuccess

parse ["-o", fn] = return fn

parse [_]        = invalidArguments >> exitWith (ExitFailure 1)

usage            = putStrLn "Usage i cant be bothered writing rn"
noArgs           = putStrLn "Error: No arguments given"
noPage           = putStrLn "No pagename given"
invalidArguments = putStrLn "Error invalid arguments"
```

I'd be glad if anyone could help.

Comment: `parse [_]` only matches lists of length 1. Use `parse _` to match the other cases. If you keep warnings on, GHC does complain about this mistake.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm stupid, thank you for pointing that out